# Modular tensor category and the pivotal or shperical condition

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

I have two related questions:

1) Is a modular tensor category always pivotal?

2) Is a modular tensor category always spherical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a remark:

> Any pivotal category which is also braided is automatically spherical.

Basically this is because with operations of braiding and identifications $X\simeq X^{**}$ of pivotal category traces in opposite directions can be identified.

Now for the first question, which is a bit confusing to me, as far as I know the definition of a MTC is as follows:

> A MTC is a semisimple ribbon category such that
>
> - There are a finite number of ismomorphism classes of simple objects.
> - The matrix $\tilde{s}_{ij}=\mathrm{tr}(\sigma_{X_i X_j}\circ \sigma_{X_j X_i})$ is invertible. ($\sigma$ is the braiding, $X_i$ are
>     simple).

where a ribbon category is defined as

> A ribbon category is a rigid braided monoidal (tensor) category which is also **pivotal**.

So answers to your questions are

1. Yes, an MTC is a pivotal by definition since any ribbon category is defined pivotal. (in fact one cannot define traces and dimensions without pivotal property).
2. Yes, since MTC is both pivotal and braided it is automatically spherical.